# Make Mendeley automatically update .bib file upon changes

Tags: bibtex, mendeley

I use Mendeley to manage my references but I write in Emacs by using the `.bib` file exported from Mendeley. Every time I add some reference to my library, I need to manually export the `.bib` file again.

Is there a way to make Mendeley automatically generate and update a given `.bib` file from a folder in my library?

Comment: I think you should ask the support of mendeley for this, they should know their own program ... Sorry, I think your question is off topic here ...

Comment: Do you have the "enable bibtex synching" option in your mendeley preferences activated?

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. That seems to be the option I was looking for.

Comment: There just seems to be no real Mendeley user forum any more. That really is a shame. I believe that Mendeley-related questions are off topic here, but some questions have at least some relation to TeX and so they are sometimes tolerated here (especially if they can be answered quickly), but I don't think TeX.SX should become the go-to Mendeley support page. ...

Comment: ... Given the current owners of Mendeley and their support practices maybe an alternative like Zotero might be more attractive (Zotero is open source, has a proper support forum and active and responsive developers; I'm not affiliated with Zotero nor am I an active user of any sort of reference manager).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @samcarter, one can select the `enable bibtext syncing` option and the files shall be automatically generated in your designated folder.

Comment: In general it would be the polite thing to ask the user who suggested the answer in the comments to write it up instead of writing up the answer yourself. I don't think samcarter is going to take offence with this and you probably don't have to delete this answer now and ask her to write an answer instead, but this is something to keep in mind in the future.